# Node.js + Express Caching

Tags: node.js, express

How do I enable caching for static files but disable for non-static page requests?

I set this statement for static and it works fine.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public') ,{ maxAge: 800000 }));
```

But, how do I set no-cache for non-static rendered page requests? (those under views folder rendered by Jade)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rendered pages shouldn't go in the public folder
put them in a folder such as views/ . Then the middleware will not cache them

Comment: my rendered pages are in views but its still caching them